# Special CSS for elements listed after each other

Tags: css

I have a list of messages in a ticket, but in between the messages I might display some ticket activity (as in "Ticket closed", "Status changed"...).

My basic HTML of a ticket and it's messages is:

```
<p class="ticket-message">My message</p>
<p class="ticket-message">Another message</p>
<p class="ticket-message">Third message message</p>
```

If a message has any activities, the HTML can look like this:

```
<p class="ticket-message">My message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Activity</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Another activity</p>
<p class="ticket-message">Another message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Some activity here</p>
<p class="ticket-message">Third message message</p>
```

If a ticket-activity is listed after another ticket-activity, I want to add some special CSS for it (like reducing the margin on the bottom of the first item).

Example:

```
<p class="ticket-message">My message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Activity</p> <== A ticket-activity is listed after this item, add special CSS for this item only
<p class="ticket-activity">Another activity</p>
<p class="ticket-message">Another message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Some activity here</p> <== This ticket-activity is listed by itself (no ticket-activity after this item), so no special CSS is needed here
<p class="ticket-message">Third message message</p>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

I've tried using .ticket-activity + .ticket-activity, but it doesn't give me the results I need.

**Update**
I've added the CSS I have and what I tried to accomplish:

```
.ticket-message, .ticket-activity {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* This CSS should only be applied to items that are followed by another .ticket-activity as per my example above */
.ticket-activity + .ticket-activity {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

/* Some custom classes like changing color on .ticket-activity */
/* ... */
```

**Update #2**
This is what I'm trying to achieve (this is just done in the DOM with inline styles): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTWrV.png

Comment: Could you add some of the CSS code you tried so we can see what you were trying to accomplish? You can change the first item based on the next I think, but if you are talking margins you could swap the top and bottom ones and remove the top margin on the second item to make the first one have a margin at the top...

Comment: @somethinghere I've updated my question to include the CSS I'm using

Comment: A commenter added a JSFiddle earlier that came close, but isn't targeting the second "group" of activities as per my update: https://jsfiddle.net/wroo6kuv/2/

Comment: How about this monstrosity https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/nga0217a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to match your image pretty closely:

```css
.ticket-message, .ticket-activity {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

.ticket-activity {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p class="ticket-message">My message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Activity</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Another activity</p>
<p class="ticket-message">Another message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Some activity here</p>
<p class="ticket-message">My message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Activity</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Another activity</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Another activity</p>
<p class="ticket-message">Another message</p>
<p class="ticket-activity">Some activity here</p>
```

Comment: Actually the `+` selector isn't even needed. Removed

Answer (score 0):

You can select the second element based on the first, but not the other way around.

Consider using top margins instead of bottom margins.

Comment: Please see my updated visual example. I'm not in control of how many activities are listed after another - might only be one, might be three. It depends on the supporters actions.

Comment: @KlaasJan — You can select the third based on the second, and the fourth based on the third too. The point is that you can't select an element based on what follows it, only on what precedes it.